# Multiple googletag.display() with Same Id

Tags: javascript, html, ads, double-click-advertising, google-publisher-tag

Assuming I've correctly [defined](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.defineSlot) a google ad:

```
googletag.defineSlot(adUnitPath, size, "ad-id-goes-here")
```

---

If I use multiple instances of the following code (`googletag.display()` with the same id) on one page:

```
<div id="ad-id-goes-here" style="width: 728px; height: 90px">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      googletag.display('ad-id-goes-here');
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Will the ad only display once (the very first instance), or will it fail to display at all?

---

According to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.display):

> Each ad slot should only be displayed once per page.

However this says nothing about failure, any thoughts?

Comment: This page has example of asynchronous usage of the `googletag.display()` - It shows multiple instances of usage. Not sure if that helps. https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1638622?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, but the example shows multiple instances of `googletag.display()` with unique ids. I need to know what happens if I use multiple instances with the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attempt to call `googletag.display('ad-id')` twice on the same ID, the ad will only display the first time and you will get the following exception for the second call:

```
"Div element ad-id is already associated with another slot."
```

You can see this output if you append `?google_console` to the URL that contains the ad units, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to display the google publisher console.

Comment: Some more info on Google Publisher Console: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/181070?hl=en